# Temporarily modify local keymap, with failsafe to restore original

Tags: keymap

The following example is based, in part, on the idea used by `set-transient-map`; however, this example uses a `local` keymap that is only active on certain text within a buffer that was set with a text-property:  `'local-map tda--dynamic-map`

**Q**:  How can the original keymap be restored automatically if the user presses any key *other than*: `up`, `down` or `SPC`?

[Assumption:  The user will be at a buffer position containing the active local keymap.]

```lisp
(let ((var-one t)
      (var-two "foo"))
  (message "Do something first.")

  (let ((primary-func
         `(lambda ()
            (message "This is the primary-func.")))

        (secondary-func
         `(lambda ()
            (define-key tda-dynamic--map " " #'original-function-one)
            (define-key tda-dynamic--map [up] #'original-function-two)
            (define-key tda-dynamic--map [down] #'original-function-three)
            (message "This is the secondary-func."))))

    (define-key tda-dynamic--map " "
      `(lambda ()
         (interactive)
         (funcall ,secondary-func)))

    (define-key tda-dynamic--map [up]
      `(lambda ( )
         (interactive)
         (funcall ,primary-func)))

    (define-key tda-dynamic--map [down]
      `(lambda ( )
         (interactive)
         (funcall ,primary-func)))))
```

Comment: I've fixed what seemed like an obvious bug.  I've left the initial `let` and `message` but I've no idea why you have those -- they seem totally irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @phils -- thank you.  `secondary-func`, in my setup, does more than just restore the original keymap ... it is essentially a finishing / wrap-it-up function that does some additional things ... and I truncated that to just a message for simplicity purposes.  It is, however, not essential to the minimal working example ... so you are correct.